# Horizontal scrolling pager with vi keys

Tags: less, pager, most

`less` and `most` use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>, but they don't use <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> for horizontal scrolling. Is there a way I can fix either of these to do that? or maybe an alternative tool that I could use as a pager that does it?

Answer (score 0):

`printf '%s %s\n' h left-scroll l right-scroll | lesskey -`

seems to work.

More details in the `less` and `lesskey` manpages.